# I'm having 6 tabitem but i want to show only 3 tabitem at a time, as u can see a small part of next tabitem is visible

Tags: android-studio, android-tablayout

[Tablayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxGZW.jpg)

I'm having 6 tabitem but i want to show only 3 tabitem at a time, as u can see a small part of next tabitem is visible
so as i slide next 3 tabitem should appear
?

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity

```
ViewPager mpager;

TabPageAdapter adapter = new TabPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), list);

mtabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
mpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(list.size());

mpager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In your xml TabLayout set

```
app:tabMode="scrollable"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [this](https://github.com/H07000223/FlycoTabLayout) library , and handle the number of visible item